# How to decode html special characters (characters with accent) in facebook share post?

Tags: php, html, facebook, meta-tags, html-entities

```
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo $title; />
```

where $title is fetched from database.

It should show title `blácv` with character *a* with an accent, but when I share the post on Facebook, I see it as `bl&aacutecv`. The HTML special character `&aacute` is not getting decoded in Facebook meta tag. But in normal meta tag it is getting decoded.
I'm already using utf-8 in meta tag on the page.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The character should end with `;` if it is an entity. Otherwise it cannot be decoded.

You should either use UTF-8, which allows ANY character to be natively coded (no entities needed), and then only `htmlspecialchars($title)`, or use the `htmlentities($title, $encoding)` together with the correct encoding string as the second parameter in your code.

Comment: I've something like $title="bl&aacute;cv" which is being translated to bl&aacutecv. But it should rather show blácv. Can you please give an example how to fix it in facebook share post?